# View list of acquired custom moves in Smash Bros 4

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Is there a way to view a full list the custom moves I've acquired in Smash Bros for Wii U without going to each character individually?  I think I've gone everywhere in the menus, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such viewable list. I believe you can see "unlocked all of X's custom moves" in the Notices list, but that's as close as you can get.

Comment: "Unlocked all of X's custom moves" is a notification, but it's not logged as a Milestone.